# background image cover different on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, background-image

This 6-tile-header on a page I'm working on looks different in Chrome and Firefox.

http://epicstudios.de/carbonbikes3/index_white.html

Chrome shows it correctly (see screenshot link below) and uses the background images to cover the whole screen to make it look like one image divided into several tiles, while Firefox makes 6 small images out of it.

How do I get Firefox to show it correctly?

How my Chrome shows it (correct): http://epicstudios.de/carbonbikes3/cb.JPG

How my Firefox shows it (wrong): http://epicstudios.de/carbonbikes3/cb_firefox.JPG

This is how each single tile is given its background:

```
background: url(../img/header_bg_red4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can put the image as background on the main div containing the tiles. Use rgba colors on the tiles, to get them red. ---Though in my case Firefox displays the images as one, like in the [first screenshot](http://epicstudios.de/carbonbikes3/cb.JPG) you linked.

Comment: When you set up your environment you should use a method to clear css of browser-only styles. Every browser has a certain way to display certain properties.

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ is the one I use but there are many out there.. if you already did this, then sorry I'm of no help :P BTW nice site